# Can threads work in an organized sequence?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python script. It is a test by the way for some hardware (automotive). 
The hardware I test has 2 processors, which gives a lot of logs (output on its own console that I can connect via Linux minicom) while it works.

Firstly, I needed to record how much time pass from my trigger activity to the processors's response messages. Let's name it- processor A and processor B. The messages have been coming up in different order. So, for not being stopped by waiting for subsequent signal (while the other could come first from the other processor) and for not making my second signal's time incorrectly higher, I used threads. Thread1 waiting for message 1 on processor A and thread2 waiting for message 2 on processor B. That worked fine, regardless of the order that messages 1 and 2 have come. I put that threads to an array and in 'for' loop started them and then in 'for' loop joined them.

But now I need to make sth like this: on 'B', I am still waiting only for one line of message output. And that works fine, the thread for that operation reads log-line and calculate correct time form trigger to that log. But on processor 'B', I have to check times for new 7 logs. So I made 7 new functions for reading this 7 new messages and calculating time for them. Assigned that functions to 7 new threads. Put them, as previously in the array. Then started them in for-loop and joined them also in for-loop.

What is the result? The only one message from B-processor is read and time is recorded correctly. But no message from A-processor is detected (although they came for sure).

And here one info — there is a function for reading console messages-logs, line by line, from the device. But it works like a stack — once read line is 'popped out' from a buffer. So my 8 threads are popping out messages they aren't interested in, and there is almost no chance for detecting a message by proper thread, before it will be popped out by the other.

So my idea for solving the problem is to make 8 threads work in strict order : 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-1-2-3... over every next log line. However... I don't know how to do that. Please, share some ideas :)

Comment: Connect them up via queues. Even single place channels would be enough. Easy enough to build with just an Event per thread.

Comment: Easiest fix is to use only a single thread :)

Comment: "So my idea for solving the problem is to make 8 threads work in strict order" - that defeats the purpose of using threads at all.

Comment: @user2357112 No, they are pipelined. 1 does not wait for 8 to finish to start on the next line.